# How do I change playback rate/speed of a video inside an iframe with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, html5-video, cross-domain

I want to create some javascript to change playback rate of a video that's embedded inside an iframe on a loaded website. The `<video>` tag is in the iframe and I'd like to set `playbackRate` on it.

I tried using `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.querySelector('video')` to get the video element, but the `contentDocument` was null, and blocked because of cross-site origin permissions.

However, there is a popular Chrome extension called "Video Speed Controller" and when I use this extension it successfully sets the video playback rate on the video inside the iframe. How is this chrome extension (which is open source: https://github.com/igrigorik/videospeed) able to set the video playback speed of the iframe?

I read their code, and they are using the same strategy: looking for iframes and video tags, and using contentDocument on found iframe tags. They are also iterating through all the DOM nodes whenever there is a document mutation (In the main script: https://github.com/igrigorik/videospeed/blob/master/inject.js). Would that allow them to get access to the video nodes?

EDIT: The extension is acknowledging cross-site origin policies and doesn't seem to be using upgraded permissions. See comment below.

thanks!

Comment: Extensions have more privileges than ordinary JS running on a page. If you're running JS on the top window, and the video is inside the iframe, and the iframe is cross-origin, there's no way to access it (or anything inside the iframe) unless you can also change stuff on the other domain

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks. But the extension comments that it is ignoring "frames (we) don't have permission to access (different origin)." (line 543) and its manifest file isn't using upgraded permissions. so it seems to be using normal privileges?

Comment: This is a guess, but an extension's inject code may not run per-tab, but per-frame, at least for most frames. It may be that the extension code runs in the native child iframe anyway. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#frames But if that's the case, I wonder what sort of frames that section of code would target that wouldn't be caught otherwise.

Comment: If you control the iframe you may want to look at [player.js](http://playerjs.io/), which is a standardized way of setting playback across frames. Parent and child frames need to support the API.